# Writing to file with changing tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics, biopython

My code runs through a sequence of DNA and takes note of positions an ORF it comes across in that sequence. I am trying to accomplish two things.

1. Make the program loop until it finds all ORFs not the first one it runs through
2. Have the results written to a text file

I have it set up to write the results in a text file, but the results are stored in a tuple (which changes every time it finds an ORF in a sequence). This makes it so that the text file at the end only contains the last ORF of the last sequence that was inputted, instead of creating a list.

My code:

```
class SeqAnalyzer :
    def __init__(self,sequence):
        self.input = Seq(sequence)
        self.reverse = self.input.reverse_complement()
        self.sequence = str(self.input)
        self.stopcodons = ["TAG", "TAA", "TGA"]
        self.start = 'ATG'
        self.length = 0
        self.result = ("+",0,0,0,0)

    def codon(self,frame):
        start = frame
        while start +3 <=len(self.sequence):
                yield (self.sequence[start:start+3],start)
                start += 3


    def ORF(self, frame, direction):
        orf_beg = 0
        for i, index in self.codon(frame):
            if (
                (str(i) in self.start) or
                (not self.start and i not in str(self.stopcodons))
                ):
                    orf_beg = index + 1
            elif i in self.stopcodons:
                orf_ending = index + 3
                length = (orf_ending - orf_beg) + 1
                if length > self.length:
                    self.length = length
                    self.result = (direction, frame, orf_beg, orf_ending, length)
                break

    def direction(self):
        direction = "+"
        for frame in range(3):
          self.ORF(frame, direction)
        direction = "-"
        for frame in range(3):
            self.sequence = self.reverse
            self.ORF(frame, direction)
        self.results()

    def results(self):
        print(self.result)
        file = open("tass2ORFdata-ATG-100.txt","w")
        file.write("{}{:d} {:>5d}..{:>5d} {:>5d}".format(
                self.result[0], self.result[1], self.result[2],
                self.result[3], self.result[4])
                )
```

The output file results in:

```
+1     0..   13    14
```

instead of all the variations the tuple contains at different points:

```
('+', 0, 4, 9, 6)
('+', 1, 5, 10, 6)
('+', 0, 0, 6, 7)
('-', 0, 4, 9, 6)
('-', 1, 5, 10, 6)
('+', 2, 0, 11, 12)
('+', 0, 4, 9, 6)
('+', 1, 5, 10, 6)
('+', 0, 0, 6, 7)
('-', 0, 4, 9, 6)
('-', 1, 5, 10, 6)
('+', 1, 0, 13, 14)
```

I have tried various ways to fix this, but so far no method has worked.

Answer (score 0):

In your `__init__` set

```
    self.result = [("+",0,0,0,0), ]
```

then later instead of assigning to `self.result` you need to `append` to it:

```
self.result.append(direction, frame, ... )
```

Then when it's time to print:

```
for row in self.result:
    file.write("...".format(row))
```